# Is it better to do stuff in subscribe or in a custom operator using RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular application, I often use something like this:

```
this._store
    .root
    .pipe(
        ..., 
        mergeMap(() => this._httpClient.get<IEvent[]>(`${this.ROUTE}/user/${id}`))
    )
    .subscribe((events: IEvent[]) => {
        this._store.update(s => {
            s.events.byUser.set(id, events);

            for (const event of events) {
                s.events.list.set(event.id, event);
            }
        });
    });
```

Basically, I'm piping my store to at the end make an HTTP request and once I get the answer, I update the store using `this._store.update`. When I think about it, most of the functions will look like that, so I was considering the idea of creating a custom operator that would allow me to do:

```
this._store
    .root
    .pipe(
        ..., 
        mergeMap(() => this._httpClient.get<IEvent[]>(`${this.ROUTE}/user/${id}`)),
        updateStore(this._store, (events: IEvent[]) => {
            s.events.byUser.set(id, events);

            for (const event of events) {
                s.events.list.set(event.id, event);
            }
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
```

That would actually work and be more readable but then I will most of the time have empty `subscribe`, so I'm wondering if it was an issue to have empty `subscribe` just because the work is done by an operator?

Comment: There wouldn't be any difference. The operators are executed in the order they are piped in and for each operator receives the modifed operator from the one above. If the custom operator is piped in at last, then there isn't difference b/n processing that information in the operator or the subscription.

Comment: `@Michael D` is that considered a good practice?

Comment: @RafiHenig It is absolutely fine (and could be practice in the team - if all team members agree to it) and it is a non-opinionated question. From a performance perspective, there is no difference. In my team, we do not write any code in `subscribe` (in fact we heavily rely  [almost 98%] on `async` pipe). We either write custom operators or use the `tap` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, there's no issue at all to leave an empty subscribe, depending on what you're doing with it, maybe you'll prefer usnig [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject).

You may also need to find an dynamic way to unsubscribe your subscription, or expose a method to do it properly.